# How to send array of object from postman which has file in it

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I want a request from postman in particular format but I don't know how to do it.

So, I want to send data from postman to my local API in array of object.
That object contains textual information and may one file and I have multiple objects like that.
for e.g. :

```
[{
   id: 1,
   question: How are you ?,
   answer: I am fine.
},
{
  id : 2,
  question: "upload your document",
  answer: [file]
}
]
```

This is how my request looks on postman,

[image]

And this is how i am getting it in backend

```
 { additonalQuestion:
   [ '12',
      'Upload your document',
      'file',
      '13',
      'How old are you ?',
      'text',
      '16' ] }
```

I am using formidable node package to read it. and following is the code

```
const formidable = require('formidable');

  const form = formidable({ multiples: true });
  await form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    console.log('fields: ', fields);
  });
```

To summarise my question , How to can i make a request from postman where i can get request like

```
[{
   id: 1,
   question: How are you ?,
   answer: I am fine.
},
{
  id : 2,
  question: "upload your document",
  answer: [file]
}
]
```

In backend.

Thank you for your time :)